# Accessing another environment inside a locaStorage

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, local-storage

I am having 2 branches of localStorage, and I need to access the first local storage.

Here is an image that shows what I mean.

[image]

When I try `console.log(Object.entries(localStorage))`,

This shows only the keys in the second one, the first one is never accessible.

If you are wondering how come I am having 2 localStorages, that's because the second localStorage is within an iframe, and the first local storage is for the main website.

Comment: the localStorage is per origin including protocol. The two seems different

Comment: @mlpungjain does that mean the second one is never accessibla?

Comment: I cannot tell. You blacked it out. Try deleting both and see if they both come back